# Negative Signal to Noise Ratio

Tags: matlab, speech-processing

What is the reason for getting negative snr value when calculating Signal to noise ratio of speech signal using matlab function SNR()?

Comment: i guess it would be because the noise had more power (or energy) than the signal had (assuming this negative SNR was expressed in dB).

Answer (score 5):

Signal to Noise ratio (SNR) is a ratio of powers, hence it's always greater than or equal to zero.

On the other hand, very commonly, SNR is expressed in decibel (dB) notation:

$$ \text{SNR}_{\text{dB}} = 10 \log_{10}\left( \frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_n^2 } \right) $$

where $\sigma_x^2$ and $\sigma_n^2$ are the signal and noise powers respectively. Therefre, $0$ dB SNR means that the signal power is equal to the noise power. And when the signal power is less than the noise power, then one gets a negative SNR in dB.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the removal of an l on "decibell", and bigger parentheses

Comment: @LaurentDuval No of course not! But in the mean time (simultanesouly!) I was editing your post! believe it or not, and see the comment there !

Comment: Funny, so can we considered a 0 dB (equal power to clean noise) memory-less system? :)

Comment: @Fat32 I mathematically get why/how SNR can be negative but you initially state that it can't be negative and then go state the opposite in your closing statement. I've a slight confusion there if you could enlighten me.

Comment: @CanSürmeli distinguish between *SNR* and *SNR in dB*... then the confusion should disappear..

Answer (score 1):

I'll write the same equation as @Fat32 did because SNR is SNR 
$$\text{SNR} = 10 \log_{10}\left( \frac{\sigma_S^2}{\sigma_N^2 } \right)$$

Mathematically speaking, the SNR is negative when the log is negative. We know that 
$$\log x < 0$$
only if $0 < x< 1$, i.e. $$\frac{\sigma_S^2}{\sigma_N^2 } < 1$$
which means that 
$$\sigma_S^2 < \sigma_N^2$$
So, when the power of your speech signal is less than the power of the noise, you'd get a negative SNR.

Comment: What could be the better ratio in db for any speech signal? Is there any to improve my negative ratio?

Comment: @Deivapriya do you mean to ask if methods do exist for improving the SNR ?

Comment: Yes, is there a way do improve the SNR?